# Android: How to make static elements in Swipe Views?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, view, swipe

I am developing an application, where I want to make a presentation of how to use it at the beginnig. I am using ViewPager with fragemts. It all works fine, but how can I make some of the elements e.g. buttons or logo static? I want them to be permanent and only background and some other elements to move or change on swipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want them to be static, then they can't be a part of the `Fragments` inside the `ViewPager`. You could put them above or below the `ViewPager` with a `RelativeLayout`, or you could have them on top by using a `FrameLayout`.

Example for static content beneath `ViewPager`

***fragment_pager.xml***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/static_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/container" />

</RelativeLayout>
```